# Variar la escala de un histograma en R sin perder datos

Tags: r, axis

Estoy haciendo un histograma en `R` y necesito que el eje `x` tenga valores de 0.01 en 0.01 sin perder ningún dato (sin hacer zoom ).

Trate de usar la función `xlim` pero para tener la escala que deseo pierdo información en la gráfica. En este momento la escala del eje x está de 0.05 en 0.05.

```
hist(dataset1$Retornos,main="Histograma de retorno de Amazon",
col="lightcyan", xlab="Retornos",ylab="Frecuencia",breaks=60, xlim=c(-0.15,0.15))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si no te interprete mal lo que buscas es algo así:

```
# generamos una muestra de datos random similar a los de la pregunta
set.seed(2019) 
a <- -0.15
b <- 0.15
l <- 0.01
x <- rnorm(n=50000, m=1, sd=1)
x <- (b - a)*(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))+a

# Calculo de la cantidad de barras
nbreaks <- (b - a) / l

hist(x, breaks=nbreaks, xlim=c(a,b), main="Histograma de retorno de Amazon",
     col="lightcyan", xlab="Retornos",ylab="Frecuencia", xaxt="n") 
axis(1, at=seq(a, b, by=l)+(l/2), labels=round(seq(a, b, by=l),2), las = 2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente tuve que generar un ejemplo de datos, pero lo fundamental es

```
hist(x, breaks=nbreaks, xlim=c(a,b), main="Histograma de retorno de Amazon",
     col="lightcyan", xlab="Retornos",ylab="Frecuencia", xaxt="n")
```

Con `xaxt="n"` logramos que `hist` no dibuje el eje `x` y luego con:

```
axis(1, at=seq(a, b, by=l)+(l/2), labels=round(seq(a, b, by=l),2), las = 2)
```

dibujamos el eje a partir de una secuencia de números que se corresponderá a cada `bin`, con `+(l/2)` centramos el eje a cada barra y con `las = 2`mostramos las etiquetas de forma vertical para que entren todas.